# merge space on linux - from /data to / (root)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, storage, partition

when i check space on centos server i see

```
# df -m

Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1           58883 54328      1558  98% /
tmpfs              15946     0     15946   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0             283    40       229  15% /boot
/dev/md2          659113    70    625556   1% /data
```

so ho can i delete /data (/dev/md2) and add all that space to /dev/md1 (/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the configuration of your raid. Can you give the contents of `cat /proc/mdstat` ?

Extend Raid device is not as simple as a regular disk partition. From the [documentation](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#5._Grow):

> Currently supported growth options including changing the active size
>   of component devices in RAID level 1/4/5/6 and changing the number of
>   active devices in RAID1.

P.S. Inserted in a comment I can not write - I do not have enough reputation.